# Period of a T-shaped pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I'm trying to calculate the period of a pendulum that has a T-shape.

1. For a normal pendulum it's $T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$ so with $L = 1m$ and $g = 9.8\frac{m}{s^2}$ it's about 2 seconds.
2. I've found $T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{I}{mgR}}$ for compound pendulum on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum).

   $I = mr^2$

   $I = 3kg * (0.33m)^2 = 0.3267kg*m^2$

   $T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{0.32 kg*m^2}{3kg*9.8\frac{m}{s^2}*0.33m}}=1.14s$.

   I assumed the center of mass to be 1/3 the way below the rotation axis.

[image]

The problem is that I'm not sure if I calculated the period of the second pendulum correctly. I think that it should be longer. Can someone tell me if my calculations are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first do this the way that I know is correct: with Lagrangian mechanics. This says that all of the physics you need is contained in the Lagrangian, which is the kinetic energy minus the potential energy.

Your three masses Left, Right, and Bottom make the kinetic energy $K = \frac 12  m (v_L^2 + v_R^2 + v_B^2),$ where $m = \text{1 kg}.$ Defining $\theta$ as the angle the bottom makes with vertical and $r = \text{1 m}$ we have $v_L = - v_R = \frac{r}{2} \dot\theta$ and $v_B = r \dot\theta$ similarly. The potential energy of the left and right are $\pm m g\sin\theta$ which cancel each other out, so the total energies of this system are:$$\begin{align}\mathcal L =~& K - U\\
K =~& \frac 12 m \left(\frac{r^2}{4} + \frac{r^2}{4} + r^2\right) \dot\theta^2=\frac 12 \left(\frac 32 m r^2 \right) \dot\theta^2\\
U =~&m g r \cos\theta
\end{align}$$We can see that the only difference between what this expression is for a single pendulum of mass $\bar m$ and radius $\bar r$ is the changes$$\begin{align}\bar m \bar r^2 ~\to~& \frac 32 m r^2\\
\bar m \bar r ~\to~ & m r
\end{align}$$But replacing $\to$ with $=$ we can actually solve for these as $\bar r = \frac 32 r,\;\bar m = \frac{2}{3} m.$ So Lagrangian mechanics says that it's the exact same motion as a pendulum with two-thirds the mass and three-halfs the radius. The period, of course, does not depend on mass and therefore your expression $T \propto \sqrt{L}$ means that the period should grow by a factor of $\sqrt{3/2} \approx 1.225,$ so if your answer was 2.01 seconds before your new answer should be about 2.46 seconds.

Probably your error comes in not paying close enough attention to the text of Wikipedia, which mentions a "radius of oscillation" beneath the center of mass. But there is an important related problem, which is that you should probably calculate the moment of inertia of this system about the point that it's actually rotating, so that you do not need to account for the torques that go through that point (i.e. the complicated constraint forces keeping the masses rotating around that point.)

Answer (score 1):

Your moment of inertia is incorrect. You must calculate is based on the individual masses and their distances from the pivot:
$$\mathcal{I}=\Large\Sigma \large\left( m_ir_i^2\right).$$

If you do this you should get an answer that agrees with what @ChrisDrost did, 2.47 s

And you shouldn't *assume* that the center of mass is 1/3 of the way below the rotation point. You should calculate what it is.

Comment: S/he did calculate it; it's just a really simple calculation. The horizontal dimension disappears because of symmetry; then you have 2m on one side of the teeter-totter and m on the other, so the COM is one third of the way down.

Comment: I know that the calculation yields 1/3 m below, and yes, it is simple. OP states they *assumed* it. Just like they assumed that the MOI was $mr^2$, when it isn't.

Comment: I calculated the 1/3 value as the center of mass using the geometric center of triangle but I mistakenly didn't mention this. Moment of inertia is the only thing that I was confused about, I don't know this "sigma" symbol yet. I never had it at school. Thank you for your explanation, now it's clear.

Comment: Okay. As a similar exercise, how would you find the center of mass if the two masses at the top were 1/3 kg each, but the bottom one was still 1 kg? (It's not the geometric center.) What would the new MOI about the pivot be? What is the new period?